# SCORM 2004 on Plateau LMS

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Tearing my hair out. Client is using Plateau (Success Factors) and SCORM 2004, single SCO. They would like detailed interaction data to go to their reports on each test attempt, failed or not. If the user fails, they get to return to the SCO, which consists of course pages and the test, and try again. When the user returns, their progress and tracking data should still be available to the course, eg they should not have to repeat the content, only retake the test.

It appears the only way to commit the attempt to the reporting is to NOT set cmi.exit to "suspend". However the only way to access the previous tracking IS to set cmi.exit to "suspend".

Please am I missing something here? I have even tried stashing my suspend_data info in an interaction but after closing out with a cmi.exit set to "normal", it starts all over again with no access to the previous interactions.

How can I get Plateau to record data on failed attempts and still allow the user to pick up where they left off? Help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Plateau LMS specifically, but it may well be that the LMS simply doesn't support displaying data for attempts in progress. It certainly seems that way from what you describe. Setting cmi.exit to "suspend" is correct if you want the learner to be able to return to the attempt.

Have you tried the course in [SCORM Cloud](http://cloud.scorm.com?utm_source=cloud_scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm_cloud?pmc=em-1)? If it works the way you want it to there, it may be worth you looking into [Dispatch](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/control-your-content-with-dispatch/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=cloud_dispatch?pmc=em-1).

Comment: It seems that you're correct - it just doesn't support attempts in progress in reporting. Works great in SCORM Cloud, but unfortunately the client needs to use their own LMS and Dispatch isn't something they'll consider. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can journal interactions, meaning you can create a history of touching the same interaction within the SCO. But your right, if you suspend you are allowing the student to continue the same attempt. And if you set exit to any other state it will end the attempt.  SCORM spec did not make any rules about how a LMS archives or reports (even saves) past attempts.

I just got into this with SCORM 1.2 in regards to some platforms keeping the student attempt stuck in eternal mode. They seem to ignore the exit mode, and favor the SCO to sort out attempts or retries.  Makes it harder to figure out when you are truly done and ready for a grade.

Comment: Yeah, frustrating - this client may just need to live with this behavior, unfortunately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We had a customer with content where they wanted interactions tracked, but did not want the course to ever mark complete.  Basically a set of job aids packaged as a SCORM 2004 course.

You can customize the SCORM Exam Detail report SQL to include in-progress sessions, though I don't know the details and you may need an LMS admin for this.

(this is for SuccessFactors, the modern version of Plateau LMS)